# Ubuntu 12.04 displays a blank screen with no wallpaper and no refresh

Tags: screen, update-manager, desktop-background

My system specs:
- Intel Core 2 Duo T7500@2.2GHz
- Graphic Card Intel Mobile GM965/GL960

Operating System - Grub Tripple Boot System:

- Ubuntu 12.04 with CairoDock 3.0.0 and Compiz Cube activated and working
- Ubuntu 11.04
- Windows 7

I updated my Ubuntu 12.04 - After this update I rebooted and was able to log in. There are no wallpapers showing and the main screen is not refreshing (this is when moving a window around the desktop there are drag-lines showing all over the screen). The only way to refresh is to activate the 3D cube. In addition the mouse-over activates inactive windows and when writing a letter moves the cursor wherever the mouse pointer is). Everything is working as before, except that I can not activate a second monitor to extend the desktop. This produces the following error:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XRANDR_2' on object at path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/XRANDR
```

Before the update no proprietary drivers were activated or necessary and everything was working perfectly (Unity 3D, Compiz Cube 3D, Wobbly Windows, Cairo Dock 3.0.0, Wallpaper Changer etc.).

I was already looking for a way to revert to the last update but there seems to be too many programs that were changed. I looked it up in the Update Change Log in 
var/log/apt/history.log

Among the updates were

- Kernel Update to 3.2.0-56
- xserver-common i386 (3.4.2-Oubuntu 0.12, Oubunti 0.13)
- xsever-xorg-core i386 (1.11.4-Oubuntu10.13,1.11.4-Oubuntu 10.14)

This problems are very annoying and I am considering to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 and avoiding the Kernel and Xserver updates! But before I do this I thought to raise the question here in order to get an answer how to fix this stupid problem more elegantly!  :-)

Oh, in case anybody asks, the other Operating Systems (Ubuntu 11.04 and Windows 7) are both still working without any problem because there is any hardware change or problem!

Any suggestions are highly welcome!!!

Answer (score 0):

The same happened here under Ubuntu 13.04 after a recent update. Draglines appear on the desktop as if the process that draws the desktop background is broken. Desktop icons appear, the Unity menu appears, all else works.

Workaround: Enable the compiz-fusion wallpaper feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with screen refresh after updating a large number of apts on 12.04 (Precise).

The login screen was normal. After logging in, however, the login box would still be visible, with my desktop icons above it. The screen would then black out (icons still visible) and the refresh rate would be extremely slow. Window drag lines would be seen. There was no problem launching programs though.

I fixed this by launching CompizConfig and checking and unchecking options. Part of my screen was still visible as I did this, so I could see if the option had an effect on my screen. Finally I found that unchecking the "Wobbly Windows" option under "Effects" seemed to fix the screen refresh problem.